# How do you pass null values for dbtype decimal?? 

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am passing a parameter into a stored procedure:

```
param = CreateInParameter("Result", DbType.Decimal);
param.Value = testresults.Result;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

sometimes `testresults.Result` will be null

How do I pass it in as NULL?

Here's my stored proc:

```
USE [SalesDWH]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Insert_TestResults]    Script Date: 12/25/2011 23:49:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_TestResults]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @TestName varchar (500),
    @Result decimal (18,4)=null,
    @NonNumericResult varchar (50)=null, 
    @QuickLabDumpid int

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [SalesDWH].[dbo].[TestResults]
           ([TestName]
           ,[Result]
           ,nonnumericresult
           ,[QuickLabDumpid])
     VALUES
           (@TestName,@Result,@nonnumericresult,@QuickLabDumpID)


END
```

If `testresults.Result` was not assigned a value, it just goes in as 0. How do I allow it to go into the database as `NULL`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
param.Value = testresults.Result==0?DBNull.Value:(object)testresults.Result;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `param.Value = DBNull.Value;` to set the value in database to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined your @Result parameter with default value null, so if you just dont pass this param it will take null.
`if(testresults.Result>0)
{param = CreateInParameter("Result", DbType.Decimal); param.Value = testresults.Result; cmd.Parameters.Add(param); }`

Answer (score 0):

Have the stored proc default the parameter to null (as you've done), then:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Result", testresults.Result);
```

If `Result` is `null`, then the parameter is omitted and the default value is used.